# Use trigger method with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would use the trigger method with a delay before the execution, I try this way:

```
$('#open-contact').delay(3000).trigger('click');
```

but the code runs instantly.

Do any of you could help me?

thank you very much

Answer (score 17, accepted):

jQuery [doc says](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

So, I would rewrite this as

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#open-contact').trigger('click');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 6):

From jQuerys documentation about delay:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

In other words you should use setTimeout() instead, ie:

```
setTimeout(function () { $('#open-contact').trigger('click'); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$('#open-contact').delay(3000).queue(function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```