# jQuery trigger() not automatically clicking on the anchor

Tags: jquery

I just have the following code,

```
$('#autoplay').delay(800).trigger('click');
```

And I just want to test it if it even works on its own before I place it into my function and it's not working locally. Is there something I need to change on it?

I just want it to automatically click on the link with the ID of autoplay. I put a delay on it  so that I can see it work a bit after the page finishes loading. Thank you

Comment: Are you getting an error? Your code seems fine so please include the rest of your code. Also, a jsFiddle.net example might help. BTW, `.delay()` only works on the effects queue (or a custom queue).

Comment: do you want to be redirected or not?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the click to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a timeout and native javascript click event to be redirected:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tRy2Q/)

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#autoplay').get(0).click(); 
}, 800);
```

If you just want to fired attached handler, i'd suggest you to use triggerHandler() which doesn't bubble, even in your case, could not be a problem:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#autoplay').triggerHandler('click'); 
}, 800);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use setTimeout like this

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('#autoplay').trigger('click');
}, 800);
```

Anyway, that's a question resolved long time ago.

[Use trigger method with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711314/use-trigger-method-with-delay)

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function is only for jQuery effects.

You should just use setTimeout():

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#autoplay').trigger('click'); 
}, 800);
```